# Error 1004 when pasting transpose to a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

When I compile this script,  macro confuses the range sometimes and I get error 1004 saying copy paste area can't be same even though I paste it in a different sheet. Appreciate if someone can let me know where I am going wrong

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
With Worksheets("1")
LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:EE" & LastRow1).Copy
End With
Worksheets("3").Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
MsgBox ("Transpose Completed")
```

Comment: The active worksheet when you run the macro is probably Worksheets("3"). Replace `Range("A1:EE" & LastRow1).Copy` with `.Range("A1:EE" & LastRow1).Copy`

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Note that if your rows count exceeds 16384 then also an error will be thrown as you will then exceed number of columns. What is the value of variable `LastRow1`?

Comment: Thanks Moacir. It fixed the problem. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest checks and updates to your macro as below.

```
Sub TransposeData()
Dim LastRow1 As Long
With Worksheets("1")
    LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow1 > 16384 Then
        MsgBox "Transpose not possible, number of columns will be exceeded!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    .Range("A1:EE" & LastRow1).Copy
End With
Worksheets("3").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox ("Transpose Completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works. I have 2000+ rows for now. Will make use of your suggestion and have a break at 16384 mark

But I believe the error happened because the code was Range instead of .Range.